# pubnub js reconnect not working for me

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I have a web chat client that is not reconnecting to pubnub when event PNNetworkUpCategory is detected.

```
SAChat.prototype.start = function() {
var _this = this;
this.pubnub.addListener({
    status: function (statusEvent) {
        if (statusEvent.category === "PNNetworkUpCategory") {
            console.log('PNNetworkUpCategory: SDK detected that network is online.' )
            _this.pubnub.reconnect();
...
```

Anybody any idea why the client is not appearing again in the channel?

Comment: You do not need to "reconnect".  once the SDK is subscribed to a channel it will always be subscribed.  If the network goes down, the SDK will automatically reconnect upon network uplink.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to help you resolve this one :)

Few questions/requests, if I may:

- SDK Version
- Your PubNub Init config
- Enable Log verbosity, and share the logs
- Screenshot/s of any error
- Code snippets

Looking forward to your answers.

Avi.