# How to reconnect in Pubnub?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am using PubNub for notifications transfer across my Js code. I am unable to figure out how to reconnect in PubNub once internet disconnects and comes back up.

having restore: true in my init and doing

```
this.listeners = {
  message: msgEvent => {
    console.log(msgEvent);
  },
  status: statusEvent => {
    if (statusEvent.category === "PNNetworkUpCategory") {
      this.pubnub.reconnect();
}}};
```

Doesn't work for me.

full code:

```
this.pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.subscribeKey,
  authKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.authKey,
  uuid,
  restore: true
  ssl: true
});

this.listeners = {
  message: msgEvent => {
    console.log(msgEvent);
  },
  status: statusEvent => {
    if (statusEvent.category === "PNNetworkUpCategory") {
      this.pubnub.reconnect();
    }
  }
};

this.pubnub.addListener(this.listeners);
```

SDK: 4.27.2

expectation: try to Reconnect PubNub  max N tries) ,subscribe to existing subscribed channels.

Comment: Lol I read the service name, that you used in title wrong :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pubnub js reconnect not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517416/pubnub-js-reconnect-not-working-for-me)

Comment: @Frasernot really. it doesn't reconnect on its own..

Comment: Then tell us: which SDK, Provide your full Init config, enable and share the logs. As is the question is "why doesn't this work" and doesn't provide enough information to answer.

Comment: @Fraser Updated question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061509/how-to-reconnect-pubnub-after-internet-reconnect-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reconnect Pubnub after internet reconnect in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061509/how-to-reconnect-pubnub-after-internet-reconnect-in-javascript)

Comment: Just update your code in the original post and provide further issues/questions there. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it you are possibly getting some other status response that you are not checking for...Also I think you would require the `autoNetworkDetection` flag to announce when the network is down or up using the states `PNNetworkDownCategory` and `PNNetworkUpCategory`. i.e.

```
this.pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.subscribeKey,
  authKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.authKey,
  uuid,
  restore: true,
  ssl: true,
  autoNetworkDetection: true
});

this.listeners = {
  message: msgEvent => {
    console.log(msgEvent);
  },
  status: statusEvent => {
    if (statusEvent.category === "PNNetworkUpCategory") {
      this.pubnub.reconnect();
    } else {
      // check for other status events - PNTimeoutCategory, PNNetworkIssuesCategory, etc
      console.log(statusEvent.category);
    } 
  }
};
```

If that fails and you still get reconnection issues you should set the flag  `listenToBrowserNetworkEvent` to `false` as this allows the SDK reconnection logic to take over. i.e.

```
this.pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.subscribeKey,
  authKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.authKey,
  uuid,
  restore: true,
  ssl: true,
  listenToBrowserNetworkEvents: false
});
```

see: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-network-lifecycle#pnnetworkupcategory

Comment: it should work with default configs except the `restore:true` is required and no need to call `reconnect`